# "УгличЕский" — ошибка или старославянский вариант?

Tags: грамотная-речь, суффиксы

Иногда встречается слово ***Угличский***, написанное через Е. В Гугле почти 44 тысячи результатов на *Углический* против 1,24 млн на *Угличский* — немного, но всё же не совсем капля в море.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном написании это можно трактовать как ошибку, но судя по старым текстам, написание "Углический" раньше практиковалось: поиск по книгам даёт много результатов, но сканы полной страницы по причинам организации поиска в русских книгах увидеть можно редко. Поэтому трудно установить, до какого времени такое написание использовалось (в текстовых, не иллюстрированных результатах мелькают даже упоминания о ГЭС и пр. объектах).
Вот удачная находка скана старого текста (Русское государство в половине семнадцатого века; "*За то Густаву было отлучено Углическое княжество...*"):

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=I0QEAAAAYAAJ&hl=ru&pg=RA1-PA50&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U3pIXPZUimXOn1NE9QMUZVpkfaYKA&w=1025